# Why Q_ASSERT instead of assert

Tags: c++, qt, assert, assertion

In Qt there is a [Q_ASSERT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_ASSERT) macro. What's the advantage of using this instead of [assert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) from `<cassert>` ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Q_ASSERT` is a custom assert macro which supposedly enhances the standard `assert` function.

The error message is handled by  **[`qFatal()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qFatal)**, which can behave slightly better on some platforms than the standard assert macro. For example on Windows it will trigger the Visual Studio debugger at the point where the assertion fails instead of just calling `abort()`.

You can also **redirect** the output of Qt error message functions such as `qFatal`to your custom message handler ( with [qInstallMessageHandler()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) ). It can be useful for example if you want to redirect the errors message to a file.

Also note that `Q_ASSERT` is disabled with the macro `QT_NO_DEBUG`(while `assert` is disabled by `NDEBUG`) : this can be used to separate your asserts between Qt-related code and the rest.

Comment: On a side note if you  want a more detailed explanation on how custom assert macros work and why they are useful, get your hands on **Squeezing more out of assert** by Steve Rabin in _Game Programming Gems_

Answer (score 6):

From the very same document:

> It does nothing if QT_NO_DEBUG was defined during compilation.

So, think about it: `Q_ASSERT` is not contingent on the absence of `NDEBUG`, as `assert` is. `#ifndef NDEBUG` is required for `assert()` to do anything and also is often used to demarcate other general debug-only things in user (and possibly library..?) code.

Using a separate macro is a benefit for those who would want to debug only Qt-related things, without leaving `NDEBUG` undefined and thus weighing down the rest of the code with debug-only stuff that'll bloat the program if `NDEBUG` is not defined, particularly `assert()`s.

So, you could compile with `-DNDEBUG` but *not* `-DQT_NO_DEBUG` if you wanted to compile 'normal' things with release-mode semantics but still apply debugging to Qt stuff.

That's surely very useful when developing a complex GUI application. I don't use Qt (yet?) but see the benefit of using such things in my chosen toolkits of GTK+/gtkmm [ ...which I'm sure exist, but I haven't yet looked them up ;-) ]

I recall a recent animated discussion on this here, interwoven with discussion of an orthogonal proposal: [ISO C++ Standard - Future Proposals ›
Exception stack trace information.](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/JvRcNmehM_A%5B26-50%5D)

Comment: Yes I noticed the different debug defines, I was wondering if there was something more to it. But it makes sense to have that possibility.